# Рекурсия. Работа со строкой

Tags: javascript, строки, рекурсия

Здравствуйте. Изучаю JavaScript, в частности рекурсию. В поисках ответа натолкнулся на рекурсивную функцию, которая получает строку и  должна  вернуть её перевернутую задом на перёд.

```
const r = (a) => a.length - 1 ? r(a.slice(1)) + a[0] : a;
```

Подскажите, что означает условие `a.length - 1` ?

Comment: Оно означает, остались ли в строке буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.length - 1`, если длина строки `a` не `0` то выполняет одно условие, иначе другое, то есть при уменьшении длины, у тебя будет `a.length-1` равен `...,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`, а это в условии `if` будет `true`, а вот когда дойдет до `0`, для `if` будет означать, что `false`, одним словом, если передать в `if` число, не равным `0`, он всегда будет воспринимать это за `true`, а если передать 0, то это означает для него `false`

Comment: постарался как можно более внятно объяснить, если оч криво получилось, прошу простить

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно, только почему не написать a.length  > 0 или так не принято?

Comment: @Saper663, хоть так и хоть этак, результат будет выполняться одинаково, но исходя из логики, без `>` код должен работать быстрее, так как меньше проверок, да и заметить разницу в маленьких объемах нереально.

Comment: Значит быстрее, вот в чём дело, понятно, спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: Допустим, есть функция callText(text). Параметр text = "Hello World"; Как мне вызвать ее, скажем, 5 раз рекурсией?  В консоли пишет  <too much recursion>. что бы не пробовал....

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan нужно добавить в функцию ещё один параметр ‘repeats’, и передать при вызове функции 5, а в функции уменьшать repeats и передавать в рекурсии уменьшенную на единицу параметр и нужно добавить проверку на то, чтобы repeats >= 0, иначе выход

Comment: function showText(text, repeats) {
    if (repeats >= 0) {
    showText(text, repeats--);
    }
    return;
    }
    showText("Hello", 5);  MaxKrasnov - Можешь указать на ошибки?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan в условии поставь return функции, а то у тебя по сути условие проходит и дальше return срабатывает, скорее всего в этом проблема

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan сорян, я с телефона и не могу нормально изменить код твой и показать, только так

Comment: А return у тебя чего? Что вообще выполняет функция?

Comment: И вот для нормального понимания https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion

Comment: return, чтобы при repeats == 0, закончилась бы работа функции. Все таки не получилась реализация...

Comment: Вот так получилось у меня: function showText(repeat) {
if (repeat > 6) {
return;
}
 else {
 repeat++;
 document.write("Hello World!" + "<br />");
  showText(repeat);
 }
}
showText(5); А как можно было по другомунаписать?